# SQL Server: recursion and overhead

Tags: sql-server

Microsoft SQL Server 2017 Web Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2016 Datacenter 10.0

I have a table of 20,000 records that need to be processed, sending info to a 3rd party using XMLHTTP object.

The processing can only take place Monday - Friday, 9:00 to 17:00: if it goes a few minutes over that's fine, but it needs to stop as soon as possible after 17:00. Starting at 16:59 with, say, ten records, for example, ends us at 17:00:10, and that works.

I figure the best way to do this is with a recursive procedure: execute 32 times (max recursion, right?), 10 records at time.

The XMLHTTP object is created only once and passed as a parameter with each iteration after the first.

In pseudo-code, then:

```
create my_procedure 

      @recursive_counter smallint = 0
    , @object_variable int = 0

as

    if (outside the allowed time) begin
        return
    end 

    if (coalesce(@object_variable,0) = 0) begin
        set @object_variable to xmlhttp
    end

    declare @table_variable (keyfield, data, processed) -- not shared through the iterations, right?

    insert into @table_variable
    select top 20-30max keyfield, data, 0 as processed
    from myTable
    where processed = 0
    and unique_value = ''

    -- assign a unique value so the procedure can be run again
    -- in another window and avoid collisions
    update a
    set a.unique_value = newid()
    from mytable a
    inner join @table_variable t
    on a.keyfield = t.keyfield

    while exists (select 1 from @table_variable where processed = 0) begin

        @object_variable 'send' the data

        set processed = 1 
        on both @table_variable and the source table

    end

    set @recursive_counter = @recursive_counter - 1

    if @recursive_counter > 0 begin
        exec my_procedure @recursive_counter, @object_variable 
    end
```

There are other programs running and I don't want to suck too many resources away from them.

Please note: I've tested the hell out of the procedure on off-hours, and it works. My question is:

What is the overhead on a recursive procedure like this? Not recreating objects, working with small data sets.

Comment: *"What is the overhead on a recursive procedure like this?"* There isn't an overhead, per say, it's just slow. T-SQL isn't a Programming Language, it's a Query Language; it excels at set based operations not iterative ones. The "overhead" is that this is likely the least efficient way of doing what you are after (without knowing what `@object_variable 'send' the data` means, as that isn't valid syntax).

Comment: Why do you think this requires recursion and can't be done in set-based operations?

Comment: As already stated, using TSQL in an iterative approach **and** (guessing here) with an external API (via the antiquated ole automation stored procedures) is not likely to be a high performance solution. A better choice is to move this logic into a service or app that can access the API in a much more robust and secure fashion.

Comment: High performance isn't that big an issue, just wanted to make sure I didn't crash the server by hogging all the memory or CPU. And Larnu : I said just before the code that it was "pseudo-code"; NONE of it is valid syntax, just meant to be illustrative of the task. Just a dozen lines in, @object_variable is shown to be XMLHTTP object. Apparently, I was unclear, then?

Comment: @Smor: an app is likely where it will go once the current fire is put out, so to speak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### SQL Server as a [Real-Time system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_operating_system)

SQL Server is not a real-time system, i.e. it cannot guarantee that a specific operation will complete in a certain amount of time or by certain time. The only tool it has to enforce that the operation will not run longer than specified is via a timeout setting, which will force abort (and rollback) execution after the specified period of time.
With some use of `BEGIN TRAN` / `END TRAN` in strategic places, you should be able to achieve hard 17:00 cut off. It will require the use of a loop though (read on).

### Thoughts on Recursion

As in all languages / systems recursion does incur context switching / context creation overhead and it will also be true of SPs in SQL Server. The relative impact of it will depend on the cost of the "useful" work your SP does. What you are doing can easily be done in a `WHILE` loop, and I suggest you do it in a `WHILE` loop.

### Thoughts on Performance

1. `Update` is the most expensive type of operation in SQL Server, closely followed by `SELECT`. In your code I can count 2 updates and 1 select on `mytable`.
2. Having an SP repeatedly hit the same table in "small chunks" will always be slower than hitting it few times in big chunks.
3. Running these SPs concurrently from different sessions will require careful index and transaction setup, else they will be blocking each other or worth you will end up with race conditions.

### My Recommendation

```
create my_procedure 
    , @object_variable int = 0
as

    if (coalesce(@object_variable,0) = 0) begin
        set @object_variable to xmlhttp
    end

    declare @table_variable (keyfield, data, processed)

    while (inside the allowed time)
    begin
        BEGIN TRAN
        -- Combine select and update
        update a
        set a.unique_value = newid()
        from
            ( select top 20-30max keyfield, data, unique_value, 0 as processed
            from myTable WITH( ROWLOCK ) -- rowlock to avoid blocking; MUST HAVE covering index
            where processed = 0
            and unique_value = ''
            order by id ) AS a
        OUTPUT keyfield, data, unique_value, processed INTO @table_variable

        @object_variable 'send' the data

        COMMIT TRAN
        TRUNCATE TABLE @table_variable

    end -- end while
return;
```